# Timed out when attempting to connect to an external TCP server (Super Simple TCP)

Tags: c#, tcp

The ports are open (I believe).
Is there a way to disregard the exception and keep trying to connect??

[Here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vxfk.png)

Comment: There are too many possible reasons why this might be failing. And no, there's no way to ignore this error, it's fatal.

Comment: You could define your own timeout (instead of the default one). ```client.ConnectWithRetries(10); // try for up to 10 seconds```

Comment: Is it your program listening or something else? Have you checked if anything is listening on port 9000 on the right interface/protocol? See [netstat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/netstat)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If it is timing out instantly, then either:

1. The server isn't listening on that port; or
2. The connection is being actively blocked by a network firewall

If it times out after a period of time then, either:

1. the traffic is being dropped by a firewall; or
2. The network is unreachable due to a network fault

Comment: I think that I opened the ports on both devices, how would I know of it is a network fault?

Comment: Are the devices on the same subnet?  Trying pining each other.  If you get no response look at the ARP table, if there is no entry then it's a network problem.  You probably need to add some code to show what you are doing,